# The use of 'involve’ vs. 'involved'

Tags: grammar

I'm confused with the use of 'involve' and ‘involved’.

Should it be:

> 1. The company is **involve** in trading and marketing

or:

> 2. The company is **involved** in trading and marketing.

Answer (score 1):

2 is correct. The infinitive of this verb is “to be involved”, so it will be involved in any tense. You can think of “involved” as an adjective with this usage.

> I was involved
>
> I am involved
>
> I will be involved
>
> I had been involved

etc.

Don’t confuse it with the verb “to involve”